# Flexbox layout for items

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm looking for a way to maintain this layout on a page for 3 items. From what I've used flex wrap but that only is only partially helpful. Is there a way to preset a layout on flexbox to something below?

[image]

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content space-between, assuming the margin on left and right are supposed to be the same. Also read https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ it's very helpful and it is illustrated with pictures

Comment: Use [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout).

Comment: What is the result that you want? could you prepare a picture of that?

Comment: We need to see your HTML to know if we can achieve the layout you want with CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Using Flexbox

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

span {
  flex: 0 1 50%;
}

#one {
  background-color: #34495e;
}
#two {
  background-color: #3498db;
}
#three {
  background-color: #2ecc71;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span id="one">1</span>
  <span id="two">2</span>
  <span id="three">3</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout):

```css
#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#container > div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<main id="container">
  <div>Item 1</div>
  <div>Item 2</div>
  <div>Item 3</div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

span {
  width:calc(50% - 2px);
  height:200px;
  border:solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>3</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would be sure to use 'justify-content:space-between' in the parent div so they always maintain that space between them.

Also added the same in margin-bottom to keep the vertical space even.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction:row;
  justify-content:space-between;
}

span {
  width:calc(50% - 10px);
  height:200px;
  border:solid 1px black;
  margin-bottom:20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>3</span>
</div>
```